# Custom UIStoryboard using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

Has anyone managed to create a custom UIStoryboard using Swift.

If you jump to the definition of UIStoryboard it only has one initialiser. However it seems to return a UIStoryboard.

```
init(name: String!, bundle storyboardBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) -> UIStoryboard
```

I though initialisers did not return a type. Anyway, when I attempt to call this super initialiser from my subclass initialiser I get the following error

**Must call a designated initialiser of the superclass 'UIStoryboard'**

Has anyone successfully done this. Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I think in your case, the approach should be to override `init(name: String!, bundle storyboardBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) -> UIStoryboard` in your subclass and call it from your new convenience initialiser

Comment: I tried this but no luck every time I try to call the initializer in the super class I get the same error. Has anyone managed this?

Comment: You should be able to call it, are you specifying your initialiser as `convenience`? If you are, you shouldn't be.

Comment: I thought you could only call a designated initialiser in a super class from a designated initialiser in the subclass. Terror seems to suggest that the initialiser I am calling in the super class is not the designated initialiser. Have you got a working example. I think I have tried every combination of possible initialiser combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class (type) method to instantiate the storyboard.

let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: nil);

Edit:
You are not supposed to subclass UIStoryboard. There are no public designated initializers for this class. Instead you are supposed to use the class method to create your storyboard, as there is a lot of private Apple API code to load the storyboard from it's compiled *.storyboardc file. The actual loading of the storyboard must be done via the class method.

Subclassing wouldn't help since the class method is only guaranteed to return a UIStoryboard, and not your specific subclass. Try to use another design pattern to achieve your goals. You could add a category (Swift extension) to UIStoryboard to add whatever additional methods you want, and call those from your code.

Comment: He's asking about calling the method from a subclass initialiser

Comment: Yes I want to create a subclass of UIStoryboard. Has anyone got a confirmed working example?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you want to subclass UIStoryboard? My impression is that UIStoryboard should not be subclassed, and that it's implementation for initialization is essentially a private API from Apple.

Comment: Oh I was not aware of that. The reason I want to subclass it is that I want to use dependency injection to inject my view controllers, model etc. It just give me control. My plan was to create the storyboard and override the two class functions to access the initial view controller and access them by string index

Comment: Not sure if this would help you, but I have a github project to allow for the linking of multiple storyboards together within the storyboard itself. https://github.com/RVijay007/StoryboardLink

Comment: Can anyone confirm whether or not we should be able to subclass UIStoryboard. Also has anyone managed to do it using Swift. If so can you post how you did it.

Comment: I have investigated further and you all you can really do is effectively wrap UIStoryboard in a class an intercept calls to the view controller initialisation methods and perform property injection. There does not seem to be a way of performing constructor injection. I think this is something Apple should improve especially now with the introduction of Swift. The level of coupling in the iOS MVC model seems very high to me. Hopefully they will introduce some new patterns in the future which will increase the use of dependency injection