# Would Apple reject my application for using this code?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, appstore-approval

I would like to know if i use the code i provided below, can my app be rejected by apple? Am i violating anything? code is in AppDelegate.m

```
- (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard {

UIStoryboard *storyboard;

// detect the height of our screen
int height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

if (height == 480) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main3.5" bundle:nil];
} else if (height == 568) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main4.0" bundle:nil];
}else {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main7.0" bundle:nil];
}

return storyboard;
}
```

Comment: What about the code are you worried about? BTW - Apple doesn't see your code. As long as you aren't using private APIs and your app works properly, Apple couldn't care less about your code.

Comment: Hi, the reason i ask is because i saw this post. Please check top answer from the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271131/custom-uistoryboard-using-swift

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything that would violate Apple's terms. However, It is important that you know Apple does not see the code. What they base their terms on is the App's performance and content. Your App can be rejected but from what I have seen you have nothing to worry about with that.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. The reason i was worried was because i saw a post. Here is the link, please read the top answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271131/custom-uistoryboard-using-swift

Comment: @LONKNOOS is that really true? How then would they know if you are using private API's?

Comment: I believe it has to be flagged and then your code would be investigated by Apple